# How to use pandas.dataframe.corr with only a specific number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say for example I have a dataset with 1000 rows, and 10 variables:
Now, let's say I want to calculate the correlation between the first 4 variables... How would I go about doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('random_data.csv')
df.corr()[0:4]
```

This code I have calculates the correlation between the first 4 variables with all the variables total in the dataset. How would I adjust this to make it a 4x4 correlation matrix and not a 4x10 correlation matrix?
Any helps thank you!

Comment: Its more of like df.iloc[:,0:4].corr() or df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].corr().

Answer (score 2):

To do this you want to use a subset of the dataframe that contains only the columns you want.

`df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].corr()`

OR

`df.iloc[:, :4].corr()` to select first 4 columns